# First person shooter camera movement

Tags: xna-4.0, camera, first-person-shooter

I am making an FPS in XNA. I cannot seem to make a FPS camera that I can move Forward, Back, Side to Side using the keyboard. How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Google has tons of information, especially on such a simple subject. Look it up on the internet, you will find it. Then, if you have a specific problem, you can ask your question here. This question is way to broad for this site.

Comment: Sorry about that.... Obviously, I'm kinda new to the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is some basic code that will work for you.

```
//class scope fields
Vector3 camPosition, camTarget;


//in the camera Update method
Matrix ViewToWorld = Matrix.Invert(view);

if(/* W key is down */)
{
   camPositon += viewToWorld.Forward * speed;//speed should include a factor of frame delta time
   camTarget += viewToWorld.Forward * speed;
}

// same code as above for S key but use viewToWorld.Backward instead

if(/* D key is down */)
{
   camPositon += viewToWorld.Right * speed;
   camTarget += viewToWorld.Right * speed;
}

//same code as above for A key but use viewToWorld.Left instead

view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(camPosition, camTarget, Vector3.Up);
```

Comment: Quick Question. When you say Matrix ViewToWorld = Matrix.Invert(view); is it supposed to be viewToWorld?

Comment: read again your question... without dude... yes.. ViewToWorld is supposed to be ViewToWorld... the view matrix converts from world to view... if you invert it... you get a matrix that converts from view to world... ;)

Comment: I don't think you understand  :P

What I'm trying to ask is was there a typo and is ViewToWorld supposed to be viewToWorld (v is lowercased)

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Sorry. They should all be same case